# Como enviar Lists com Retrofit 2.0 via POST

Tags: java, android, rest

Tenho uma lista de registros e preciso enviar para o servidor via POST, uso Retrofit 2.0 para fazer as requisições. Conseguir fazer todas as requisições, porém não estou conseguindo enviar a lista.

Minha interface:

```
private interface SalesService{

   @POST(API_BASE + "/registrar")
   Call<List<Registro>> sendRegisters(@Body List<Registro> list);

}
```

Método de requisição de Registros:

```
public void senRegisters(List<Registro> registros) throws IOException {
    SalesService service = requestApi.create(SalesService.class);
    Call call = service.sendRegisters(registros);
    call.execute().body();
}
```

Estou executando o método sendRegister() em um IntentService.

O lado do servidor foi criado usando PHP Slim Framework. O método que recebi a requisição é:

```
$app->group('/api/escolas', function() use ($app){
    //recebe registros das turma e salva no banco de dados
    $app->post('/registrar', function() use ($app){
        $request = $app->request;
        $registros = json_decode($request->getBody());
        foreach($registros as $reg){
            $class = $reg->turma;
            $count = $reg->qtdAlunos;
            $app->db->insertRegister($count, $class);
        }
        exit;
    });
});
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema mudando trocando a lista de `List<Registro>` por um array `Registro []`